# How does the epoch-based reclamation work step-by-step, specifically, the EBR with 3 epochs in it?

Tags: lock-free

I checked some online resources to find out how the EBR epoch-based reclamation strategy work in c++ lockfree code. But I still do not fully understand it.

Is there a nice and simple way to learn it step-by-step?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you don't understand? I can refer you to my [Master's thesis](https://repositum.tuwien.at/bitstream/20.500.12708/4346/2/Poeter%20Manuel%20Johannes%20-%202018%20-%20Effective%20memory%20reclamation%20for%20lock-free%20data...pdf) which contains a general explanation of EBR, as well as an explanation of the implementation I did back then (the original code can be found [here](https://github.com/mpoeter/emr)). I later refactored and extended it a bit and published the new version as part of my [xenium library](https://github.com/mpoeter/xenium/).

Comment: I checked one online slide: https://dcl.epfl.ch/site/_media/education/ca20_lecturemr.pdf, page 45: is the "epoch integer" per-process, or a global atomic<int>? I ask because I see from other sources that 'epoch integer' is a global one. page 46: "together with epochs from all other processes": it sounds expensive? and many other questions. I generally feel that this topic has no textbook-like tutorial, or no tutorials at all.

Comment: Yes, the topic of concurrent memory reclamation is a quite difficult one, and unfortunately there are very little resources on it except for the various research papers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Epoch based reclamation (EBR) was first described by Keir Fraser in his thesis [Practical lock-freedom](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/techreports/UCAM-CL-TR-579.pdf) - so this can be seen as the canonical reference.

EBR is based the concept of grace periods. A grace period is a time interval [*a, b*] such that, after time *b*, all nodes removed before time *a* can safely be reclaimed. Nodes that have been removed from data structures are kept in *limbo lists* that hold the references to the nodes until it is safe to reclaim them (i.e., until no stale references can possibly exist).

In EBR the programmer has to define a critical region in which a thread is allowed to access shared objects. (Note: this *critical region* has nothing to do with the term critical section that is often used in the context
of mutual exclusion) These regions have to be entered and left explicitly. A *global epoch count* is used to determine when no stale references exist to any object in a limbo list.

Every thread has a flag that indicates whether this thread is currently in a critical region, as well as a local epoch count that identifies the epoch it currently executes in (in case it currently is inside a critical region). The thread's local epoch count may lag at most one epoch behind the global epoch. Each time a thread enters a critical region it sets the flag and observes the current epoch, i.e., it updates its local epoch to match the global epoch. A thread that removes a node from a data structure places this node on the current limbo list (i.e., the limbo list that is associated with the current epoch).

After some predetermined number of critical region entries, a thread will attempt to update the global epoch. This succeeds only if all threads in a critical region have already observed the current epoch. In that case the limbo list that was populated two epochs ago can safely be reclaimed and the list itself can immediately be recycled and reused for the next epoch. Thus only
three epochs (and limbo lists) are required in total.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Makes more sense to me now. Once all threads observed the 2nd-epoch (which is equivalent to say the global epoch is in the 3rd-epoch now), then all registered memories in the 1st-epoch's limbo lists can be reclaimed. I can see that in practice, there are many details to pay attention to: 1, I think every thread has its own 3 limbo lists, and these limbo lists are plain list w/o any lock, but that's ok as long as the GC is single thread; 2, a thread cannot stay in the epoch-region for long time, otherwise the global epoch cannot move on, GC cannot move on. 3, etc etc etc.

Comment: There is still actually no guarantee that how soon the GC will reclaim the memory. The GC will eventually reclaim the memory as long as global counter moves forward, but there is no guarantee about the length of the limbo list. But it's OK, as long as developer write friendly code, things will probably work just fine. I also heard a topic about "renewing epoch", which is probably about loosening the stringent requirement of exiting epoch quickly. Lockfree coding alone is complex enough, the memory reclamation triples the complexity.